# Get error after all operations do their work [nusoap,wsdl,php]

Tags: php, asp.net, wsdl, nusoap

When my users connect with nusaop and wsdl to me from asp.net they can finish their operation but in the end after all works do successfully they get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:enqueueResponse xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/enqueue/index.php">
      <return xsi:type="xsd:string">20</return>
    </ns1:enqueueResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--.
```